# Why is my hx-trigger not triggered using from: <css selector>?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, htmx

I have a button that I want to send two requests to the server when clicking. The setup is like this:

```
<button id="add-item" hx-get="some-url" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#item-form" hx-swap="beforeend" type="button">Add item</button>

<br>
<div hx-get="some-other-url" hx-trigger="from: #add-item" hx-swap="beforeend">
        
</div>
```

I have tried using `hx-trigger="click from: #add-item` but that does not work either.

The first request sent by add-item is fetched from the server correctly, but the second one from the div is never sent at all. When changing the trigger for the div to something like `hx-trigger="click"`, it works (also needing some content inside it to click).

Is there soemthing wrong with the syntax or why would this not work?

I have imported HTMX like so:  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10" integrity="sha384-D1Kt99CQMDuVetoL1lrYwg5t+9QdHe7NLX/SoJYkXDFfX37iInKRy5xLSi8nO7UC" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem:

```
hx-trigger="from: #add-item"
```

replaced with

```
hx-trigger="click from:#add-item"
```

Specifying the event by writing click was necessary as well as removing the space between from:  and #add-item.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing might be related to the way you're using the `hx-trigger` attribute. HTMX's `hx-trigger` attribute determines what action triggers the request to the server. When you use `hx-trigger="click from: #add-item"`, it's trying to listen for a click event from an element with the ID `add-item`. However, it seems that the button with the ID `add-item` is the one triggering the request, not the div.

To send two requests upon clicking the button with ID `add-item`, you can set up your HTMX attributes as follows:

```
<button id="add-item" hx-get="some-url" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#item-form" hx-swap="beforeend" hx-trigger-boost="true" type="button">Add item</button>

<br>
<div hx-get="some-other-url" hx-trigger="click: #add-item" hx-swap="beforeend" hx-trigger-boost="true">
</div>
```

Here's what's changed:

1. Added `hx-trigger-boost="true"` to both elements. This ensures that
   the triggering event propagates to the parent element (the `div`) when
   the button is clicked.
2. Changed `hx-trigger` on the `div` to `hx-trigger="click: #add-item"`. This
   means the div will listen for a click event from the element with
   the ID `add-item`.
3. With these changes, when you click the "Add item" button, it will
   trigger both requests as intended.

Comment: I made the changes but it still does not seem to work. I also can not find anything online about hx-trigger-boost. Should it be possible to send 2 different requests like this using htmx?

Comment: try like this `<button id="add-item" hx-get="some-url" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#item-form" hx-swap="beforeend" type="button">Add item</button>

<br>
<div hx-get="some-other-url" hx-trigger="click" hx-swap="beforeend">
</div>`

Comment: That would just trigger the div when clicking it @Romer. That is not what I am trying to do.